# UTF-8 Decoding And Fonts

Tags: linux, fonts, unicode

I created an application that users write fancy texts. The only problem is that I don't know how to make command-line render this utf-8 charterer. It works well on every other charterers but it fails to render or show this: `\xEF\xAE\xA9`

Do I need to install specific font for this? or is there a bug? or is there any settings which i have to fix?

By the way I use Ubuntu 20.04 And it looks like an empty rectangle on the default Ubuntu terminal.

**ScreenShot**
[image: The Rectangle Unidentified Charterer]

Comment: Here it is the weird looking character: `ﮩ`

Comment: `EF AE A9` is the UTF-8 encoding for [U+FBA9 (ARABIC LETTER HEH GOAL MEDIAL FORM)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fba9/index.htm) and obviously you need a font that supports this character in order to see it properly, otherwise the font renderer just prints out a rectangle or a `?`

Comment: And eventually try with an other terminal. In any case, the trick is that you are using presentation form, and not normal Arabic characters, so normal Arabic fonts may not be enough.

Comment: @phuclv Thanks for your answers